# Why can I not select any vertices at all?

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

I have been trying to select any vertices, faces or edges. It refuses to select anything.

I have selected the required selection on the bottom of the screen for vertex selection still it refuses to let me do it.
All my settings are defaults. I am stuck, no matter what I do!

I clicked <kbd>LMB</kbd>, <kbd>RMB</kbd>, even clicked down on my scroll, No success.

Why can I not select any vertices?

Comment: hit Tab to enter edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

This is weird. Check the following:

1. The selected *Object* is a *Mesh* (not a *Lamp*, *Camera*, *Empty* or other form of weirdom).
2. You are in *Edit Mode*. To check this, look at the lower part of the *3D-View* for selectable box with the text ***Edit Mode*** or ***Object Mode***.
    If you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> (with your cursor in the *3D-View* proper), it should switch between *Edit-* and *Object Mode*.
3. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select / deselect all vertices. 
   IF no visible change happens, you are doing art. Else, it is the vertexial selection that fails.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "IF no visible change happens, you are doing art" !!!

Comment: Or magic. Either way whatever you are doing won't be understood by yours truely.

Answer (score 1):

Found another possible cause, if things are hidden.   Fixed mine by going to mesh - show/hide - reveal hidden (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>).